# resume playing swf object after fade out and fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, fadeout

I've this `swf object` in my web page

```
<div class="video-now-playing-div"  style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto">
  <object class="now-playing" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../includes/vdbplayer.swf?volume=50&url=video.mp4" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="../includes/vdbplayer.swf?volume=50&url=video.mp4" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  </object>
</div>
```

and jQuery functions

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#fadeout").click(function(e) {
        $('.video-now-playing-div').fadeOut();
    });
    $("#fadein").click(function(e) {
        $('.video-now-playing-div').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

that works fine ,

but after `fadeOut()` then `fadeIn()` the video is played from the beginning .

Any suggestion to resume ?

**NOTE**

I don't want to use `opacity:0` or `width:0;height:0` to hide the player.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [jQuery SWFObject](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/) plugin.

```
function(){
        $('#containerID').flash('your.swf');
    }
);
```

Comment: `$('#yourVideoID').get(0)` means `<object class="now-playing">` or `<param name="movie">`?

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).get(...).pause is not a function`

Comment: sorry, got mixed up with video... You might need to use a plugin to easily do this. See my edit.